# Media player in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to use the **media player to play a music from the song collection**.

Is it possible to **code that the playing music cannot be pause**?

Below is my code:

```
private void songListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    songSelectedIndex = songListBox.SelectedIndex;
    using (var ml = new MediaLibrary())
    {
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        MediaPlayer.Play(ml.Songs[songSelectedIndex]);
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;

        MediaPlayer.Volume = 20.0f;
    }
}
```

---

I tried to use the **CanPauseProperty** but there is an error

MediaElement.CanPauseProperty = false;

Error: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'**

Answer (score 1):

MediaPlayer does not support this ability.

If you were using the BackgroundAudioPlayer (in Mango) then you can control which navigation options are available.

Comment: I think is just a normal media player. what is the different between the mango

Comment: Oh i am not using the background audio player

Comment: @ben That's why I said "if you were using" it.

Comment: i am not using that. Is do not allow pause allow to be  use in media player not backgroundAudioPlayer??

Comment: @ben The MediaPlayer and BackgroundAudioPlayer are different things. You cannot prevent pausing of the MediaPlayer (if the underlying media supports it) with BAP you can